# S3 partitioning strategy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

fully aware of the documentations about how to name a S3 object within a bucket to optimize performance

can not understand the example in this article https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-performance-tips-tricks-seattle-hiring-event/

```
2134857/gamedata/start.png
2134857/gamedata/resource.rsrc 
2134857/gamedata/results.txt
2134858/gamedata/start.png
2134858/gamedata/resource.rsrc
2134858/gamedata/results.txt
2134859/gamedata/start.png
2134859/gamedata/resource.rsrc
2134859/gamedata/results.txt
```

the article says "All these reads and writes will basically always go to the same partitio"

but we should have three partitions

2134857, 2134858, 2134859

, right ?

if we reverse the id

```
7584312/gamedata/start.png
7584312/gamedata/resource.rsrc
7584312/gamedata/results.txt
8584312/gamedata/start.png
8584312/gamedata/resource.rsrc
8584312/gamedata/results.txt
9584312/gamedata/start.png
9584312/gamedata/resource.rsrc
9584312/gamedata/results.txt
```

we have also three partitions 7584312, 8584312, 9584312

what is the difference.

What is the definition of a prefix and its relationship to partitioning strategy.

Comment: 2134857, 2134858, 2134859 are adjacent values, so more likely to be a single partition...  but unless you're doing in excess of 100 writes per second, sustained, you are probably chasing a premature optimization.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thx for the comment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The S3 partitioning does not (always) occur on the full ID. It will usually be some sort of partial match on the ID. It's likely your first example will be on the same partition using a partition match of, say, 2134, 21348, or 213485.

More info from the blog post you linked to:

> As we said, S3 has automation that continually looks for areas of the
>   keyspace that need splitting. Partitions are split either due to
>   sustained high request rates, or because they contain a large number
>   of keys (which would slow down lookups within the partition). ... This split 
>   operation happens dozens of times a day all over S3 and simply goes unnoticed 
>   from a user performance perspective.